# Creating a 2 Dimensional array with a space separated user input

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, whitespace, outofrangeexception

I am a beginner level coder in Python language. So, I need to create a 2D array list using Python. Here, the input should be with a space separated one. I have tried many ways such as import sys method, raw_input method,etc. These are the errors;
arr[i][j]=[int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Here is my code:

```
    import sys 
    n = int(input()) 
    arr=[] 
    for i in range(n):
       for j in range(3):
          arr[i][j]=[int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
       
    for i in range(n):
       for j in range(3):
          print(arr[i][j])
```

Comment: Post the code more clearly and error messages in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

```
arr[i][j]=[int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
```

you cannot call, for example, `arr[0][0]` when `arr` is empty.

You need to `append` an empty list during each iteration of `n`:

```
import sys 
n = int(input()) 
arr=[]

for i in range(n):
    arr.append([])
    for j in range(3):
       arr[i].append([int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]])
       
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(3):
      print(arr[i][j])
```